# V Look Up within same dataframe multiple times to track a ID change

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was looking for a fast way of searching elements in the same dataframe.
Suposse I have a dataframe like this:

```
Out[61]: 
   Old ID   New ID
0  1        2
1  2        3
2  3        6
3  6        10
```

And I would like to follow that chain to get the last ID for every row. Like this:

```
Out[61]: 
   Old ID   New ID   Last ID
0  1        2        10
1  2        3        10
2  3        6        10
3  6        10       10
```

How can I achieve this without looping it many times? Since I don't know how many ID changes the product had, and the dataframe has 31k rows.
I also would need it to be efficient since is a large dataframe. I was thinking about merging it with a copy of itselft multiple times but it seems a heavy operation

Answer (score 1):

Consider it a graph problem. Use [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/) to find the connected components and the leaf of each subgraph:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Old ID', target='New ID',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph)

def get_leafs(G, g):
    return (x for x in g if G.out_degree(x)==0)

mapper = {}
for g in nx.weakly_connected_components(G):
    leaf = next(get_leafs(G, g), None)
    for n in g:
        mapper[n] = leaf

# mapper:
# {1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10, 6: 10, 10: 10}

df['Last ID'] = df['Old ID'].map(mapper)
```

Output:

```
   Old ID  New ID  Last ID
0       1       2       10
1       2       3       10
2       3       6       10
3       6      10       10
```

Your Graph:

[image: graph]

Alternatively, using recursion and [`functools.cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache):

```
from functools import cache

d = df.set_index('Old ID')['New ID'].to_dict()

@cache
def find_last(node):
    if node in d:
        return find_last(d[node])
    return node

df['Last ID'] = df['Old ID'].map(find_last)
```

##### timing

On 100k rows, with nodes selected randomly from 0 to 200k without replacement.

```
# networkx approach
200 ms ± 20.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# recursion approach
29.1 ms ± 4.21 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```